# Large iPA size for iPhone Deployment target 12.1 or below(Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, app-store

If I create a SingleView Swift sample with default IDE implementation and generate iPA(Swift) with Target deployment 12.1 or below and sign it using **AppStore distribution**, iPA size comes around 112MB.

I see a duplicate swift library in SwiftSupport and framework folder of iPA.

- iPA size comes around 50KB

  - if deployment target is 12.2
  - Or sign using Enterprise or development certificates
  - Or if it is a objective C Project.

Include standard swift library option is disabled.

Issue seen in both Xcode version 10.2.1 and 10.1

Comment: 112mb for ios 12.1, and 50 kb for ios 12.2?!

Comment: Yes. Size is increased only because of dylib files like CoreData, Metal etc. This project has a default empty implementation

Comment: In other case unzipped archive will not contain SwiftSupport and framework folder in .App file

Comment: This is to be expected.  One of the big updates in iOS 12.2 when using Swift 5 is that it is binary compatible meaning that it no longer needs to have the basic libraries included in the iPA because it's guaranteed that the correct compatible ones are on the device.  Before iOS 12.2 or Swift 5 these libraries need to be included in the iPA.  This article talks about the compatibility: (https://swift.org/blog/abi-stability-and-more/)

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth Thanks, Apple has cellular data limit of 150 MB, but these libraries itself consuming major portion of the alllowed size right ?